# How to cross-compile executable for iOS and run it from iOS app?

Tags: ios, cross-compiling

This may sound a bit tricky, but i need to compile any executable (let's say "hello world") for iOS platform, pack it in iOS app bundle and run it on button click in iOS app. Is it possible? It's just a proof of concept.

PS. I know that i can use `NSTask` on device after jailbreak to run process from iOS app.

Comment: Jailbreak is the only way you would do something like that.

Comment: Sure, how to cross-compile the sources for iOS using XCode? I have just learnt how to save file in app bundle and get it from bundle on device. For android i should just use ndk and get standalone toolchain from it using script. Now i need to do the same for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `itms-services` URL scheme to install an application from a URL.

Pre-iOS 7.1 I had an application that could do this by starting a local HTTP server (using [CocoaHTTPServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer)) however in iOS 7.1, all manifests going through the itms-services url scheme had to use https and the local http server didn't support that.

I guess you could look at getting cocoahttpserver to support HTTPS or host the files remotely to achieve this?

This would work without a jailbroken device providing your device is either provisioned to install the ipa or the ipa is signed with an enterprise certificate.

Comment: the aim is not to install ios app, but run executable from iOS app, get it's output and use it

Comment: Ahh, sorry... I wouldn't know how to do this but i'm guessing you need to be jailbroken